# How to add all int values in a dict

Tags: python, int, typeerror

So, imagine I got a dict like this:

```
dict = {
    "100311929821626368" : {
        "battles" : 2,
        "loses" : 0,
        "maxstamina" : 50,
        "news" : True,
        "stamina" : 50,
        "weeb" : "Chuey",
        "wins" : 0
    },
    "100802430467325952" : {
        "battles" : 4,
        "loses" : 0,
        "maxstamina" : 50,
        "news" : True,
        "stamina" : 45,
        "weeb" : "Red Haired Bastard",
        "wins" : 0
    },
    "101970309296447488" : {
        "battles" : 1,
        "loses" : 0,
        "maxstamina" : 50,
        "news" : True,
        "stamina" : 45,
        "weeb" : "Niusky",
        "wins" : 1
    }
}
```

and my code is this code:

```
wow = 0
for id in dict:
   for i in dict[id]["battles"]:
      wow += i
```

The problem is, I'm not sure how to add all the battles int at once. Because I get this error:

```
TypeError: 'int' object is not iterable
```

How would i fix it so it all all the battles in the dict!

Comment: `sum(x['battles'] for x in dict)`

Comment: Just in case this is actually in your real code. Avoid using `dict` to actually store your dictionary. `dict` is a built-in used to create a dictionary.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Is this what you want?

```
wow = 0
for id in dict:
     wow += dict[id]["battles"]
```

Explanation if necessary: `dict[id]["battles"]` already returns the int value. You were trying to iterate over that int which makes no sense.

Comment: Explain what they did wrong. It will help the OP more with understanding why what they are doing is wrong.

Comment: OMG YES, U R BRILLANT.

Comment: Put it in your answer. Make it more complete.

Answer (score 1):

This is a duplicate of this question: [Iterating over dictionaries using 'for' loops](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3294889/iterating-over-dictionaries-using-for-loops-in-python)

key is just a variable name.

```
  for key in d:
```

will simply loop over the keys in the dictionary, rather than the keys and values. To loop over both key and value you can use the following:

For Python 2.x:

```
  for key, value in d.iteritems():
        wow += value["battles"]
```

For Python 3.x:

```
  for key, value in d.items():
```

Comment: Given they don't need the key at all, `itervalues()`/`values()` would be even more direct.

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that `dict[id]['battles']` is an object of type int, so that is the reason you are getting the error `TypeError: 'int' object is not iterable`.

You can solve it by:

```
wow = 0
for key in dict:
   wow += dict[key]['battles']
```

Or, you can even simplify the code by using a Python comprehension:

```
wow = sum(dict[key]['battles'] for key in dict)
```